# PySpark executing queries from different processes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-multiprocessing

Is there any way to have two separate processes executing queries on Spark? Something like:

```
def process_1():
   spark_context = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
   data1 = spark_context.sql("SELECT * FROM table 1").toPandas()
   do_processing(data1)


def process_2():
   spark_context = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
   data1 = spark_context.sql("SELECT * FROM table 2").toPandas()
   do_processing(data1)

p1 = Process(target=process_1)
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=process_2)
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

The problem is how to create separate SparkContexts for processes or how to pass one context between processes?

Comment: and what's your `create_spark_context` definition?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Vitaliy To be precise. I'm using Spark to download data from Iceberg table. Each query returns something like 15GB of data. Then I need to process it. So for this reason I need two processes.
I've tried to get all data in one process and then pass one to seperate process but I'm running out of memory.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm creating context like this (only with some parameters):
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

Comment: Spark il already a multiprocess framework. Why don't you use it as so ?

Comment: @Itération122442 Yes it is and this is why I'm using it. I need to extract data from Iceberg suing spark and then do a processing on the data locally. So I need two processes for performance of processing.
each query returns something like 15GB of data and then the data needs to be splitted and run to different APIs.

Comment: But why processing it locally ? Distribute it with spark, it should be faster.

Comment: @Itération122442 the processing cannot be done anymore with spark as it need some pretty complex logic and bunch of other APIs where I'm sending the data. I'm soing all I can in Spark already.

Comment: Assuming that your ultimate purpose is the processing of the data and depending on the complexity of 'do_processing'- I'd turn it into a udf and run it on the data. 
This way you are using the full potential of Spark.
You can later write the _already processed_ data back to storage

Comment: @Vitaliy Yes that was my idea yesterday and I've spend whole day on it. Unfortunately the blocker is a bug in AWS that prevents me sending queries with bigger payload to SageMaker. The queries with small payloads work but with bigger fails. They work from the Driver though. This is a known issue but no solution so far.
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3359   
https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/2843

Comment: Arent you querying Spark? what is the 'payload' of the query? (I may be missing something- I am not familiar with SageMaker but have a lot of experience with udfs and Spark)

Comment: @Vitaliy Yes I created all the queries to Spark and UDF that does what it should do. Meaning I'm grouping my data by some key then call applyInPandas() on that to do the processing. When the groups are small then it works but for bigger groups, although still in sageMaker limits, it fails with the SSL error as in the issues I pointed. 
They say that AWS has some issue with certificates in EMR and cannot authenticate itself to other services in AWS.

Comment: Got you. Do you know whether the problematic big groups are outliers or very common? 
If they are outliers you can consider filtering them out. I've had situatios where this was legit.

Also, how complex is your udf? did you consider implementing the processing in terms of SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PySpark** holds its *Context* as a singleton object.

> Only one `SparkContext` should be active per JVM. You must `stop()`
> the active `SparkContext` before creating a new one.
>
> `SparkContext` instance is not supported to share across multiple
> processes out of the box, and PySpark does not guarantee
> multi-processing execution. Use threads instead for concurrent
> processing purpose.

As for your "out of memory" problem (in your code): that could be caused by `DF.toPandas()` which significantly increases memory usage.
Consider writing the loaded data into [parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/) files and optimize computations with [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html) functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes this is what I learned the hard way about Spark. Just wanted to make sure if there isn't any way around it.
The threads aren't good for me as I need to do some CPU heavy operations on the data I'm getting from Spark and I have some spare cores for that. 
i also cannot send the data to processes as I don't have enough of memory for that (as I said before one query returns 15GB of data). So no luck I guess with this one.

Comment: @Pawel, check my additional thought

Comment: Thank you Robert. Yes it seems like toPandas() consumes more memory that maybe it should. I'm using pyarrow already. I wanted to avoid exporting to files for performance reasons and use memory only.
After your response I see there is no point of more trying to do it like that and I need to find some other solution. Thank you once again for this clarification.

Comment: @Pawel, you're welcome, and good luck with tackling that data